# How to make bootable ubuntu from installed pc?

Tags: 12.04, boot

I already posted to this question in stack exchange but this is suitable to Ubuntu . That's why I asking here again.  I don't know this is a right question . But I want to know whether can I make a bootable Ubuntu for my friend from my already installed Ubuntu desktop ? I.e. I want to make a bootable copy of Ubuntu for installing to my friend PC . But I have a desktop which already contain Ubuntu OS . Any possible way to make a bootable Ubuntu from my already installed Ubuntu Desktop ? Any software or tool can I use ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this within Ubuntu. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) is a guide on the official site.

Comment: can I make bootable with out downloaded ISO file ? I don't want to install using download ISO

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall) is a help page that demonstrates how you would make a install from a already installed system.

Answer (score 0):

The following article answers your requirements precisely

[Create a live system ISO for your Ubuntu-based Linux machines using Systemback](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/)

To work your friend's PC has to have similar enough hardware that the drivers are going to work...